# Telerik grid manage filter icons

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, grid, telerik

I#m using Telerik Grid and MVC3. I managed it to build my own filterDialogs, we had to create custom filter for each column. Everything works fine, when I click on my filter button, the gridData gets filtered. The only thing is that the filter icon doesnt change its state to active. So i went along and added the needed class after my filter command:

```
grid.filter(filterSettings)
$j('#targetColumn').addClass('t-active-filter');
```

When I filter for a first column, it works. But if I filter for a second column, the filter icon of the first column turns its state back to inactive. There must be some information that is sended from the server to the grid, so the grid goes along and adds/removes the class to the column header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/show-column-is-filtered.aspx). Before filtering I have to set the column filtersetting mannually:

```
var column = grid.columnFromMember(PropertyName);
if (column) {
    column.filters = [filterSettings];
}
grid.filter(filterSettings)
```

And everythin works :)